Power BI Service: Display Totals in Visual Table
I built a report in my Power BI Workspace and want to display the totals of specific columns of my table visual. For some reason it just doesn't turn out the way I expect.
The table columns are dragged from the Data pane, fed by a DataSet and there are some calculation columns that I added.
I activated "Totals" in the Format tab of the Visualizations pane for that table
This causes that the calculated columns of type text display a 1 in the total row, while all other columns do not display anything.
Not even the numeric columns that have proven to be numeric, as they have an underlying calculation.
Googling I read that in the Visualization pane ( in tab “Build visual”) where the columns of the table are listed, one would be able to select the summarize method (Sum, Average, Min, max) but I don’t see these options. My column related menu in that spot finishes with the greyed-out option “Show items with no data”.
I don’t have a clue what’s going on here. Somebody can explain what am I missing?
What is that 1 in the Total row? Maybe this is a hint?
Thanks for any comment.
